# Transmitting Audio stream with Pyaudio and RTP

Tags: python, sockets, audio, streaming, rtp

I have been trying to transmit an audio stream over the network with pyaudio using RTP/UDP.

Since I could find any RTP library so I did my own encoding with some help from articles online.

The problem I am facing right now is when I don't use the RTP library everything works well but when I use the RTP encoding there is some latency issue, I receive chopped-up audio on the receiver side.

I am sharing sender , reveiver and rtp code here.

Any help is appreciated.

**Sender_rtp.py**

```
import pyaudio
import sys
import socket
import datetime
import pyrtp_2 as rtp
import random

HOST = sys.argv[1]
PORT = sys.argv[2]

data = bytes() # Stream of audio bytes 

CHUNK_SIZE = 1024
BROADCAST_SIZE = 1024
CHANNELS = 1
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16 # 2 bytes size
RATE = 16000

# instantiate PyAudio (1)
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# define callback (2)
def pyaudio_callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    global data
    data += in_data
    return (None, pyaudio.paContinue)

# open stream (3)
stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK_SIZE,
                stream_callback=pyaudio_callback)

# start the stream (4)
stream.start_stream()

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
#sock.bind((HOST, int(PORT)))

def send_data():
    global data
    print()
    if (len(data) > BROADCAST_SIZE):
        packet_vars = {'version' : 2,
                    'padding' : 0,
                    'extension' : 0,
                    'csi_count' : 0,
                    'marker' : 0,
                    'payload_type' : 97,
                    'sequence_number' : random.randint(1,9999),
                    'timestamp' : random.randint(1,9999),
                    'ssrc' : 185755418,
                    'payload' : data}
        rtp_packet = rtp.GenerateRTP(packet_vars)

        sock.sendto(rtp_packet[:BROADCAST_SIZE], (HOST, int(PORT)))
        
        data = data[BROADCAST_SIZE:]
        print(f'Sent {str(BROADCAST_SIZE)} bytes of audio. {datetime.datetime.now().time()}')

try:
    while True:
        send_data()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\nClosing stream...')
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()
    sock.close()
```

**Receiver_rtp.py**

```
import pyaudio
import sys
import socket
import pyrtp_2 as rtp

HOST = sys.argv[1]
PORT = sys.argv[2]

data = bytes() # Stream of audio bytes
is_receiving = False

CHUNK_SIZE = 1024     # Size of frame window to write audio (frames_per_buffer)
BROADCAST_SIZE = 1024  # Socket receives audio with this size
BUFFER_SIZE = BROADCAST_SIZE * 4      # Receive this amount of data before playback
CHANNELS = 1
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16 # 2 bytes size
RATE = 16000

# instantiate PyAudio (1)
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# define callback (2)
def pyaudio_callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    if not is_receiving:
        return (bytes([0] * frame_count * CHANNELS * 2), pyaudio.paContinue)

    global data
    try:
        # Cut the data, if it started to bufferize 
        if len(data) >= BUFFER_SIZE * 2:
            print('Cutting Audio Buffer..')
            data = data[-BUFFER_SIZE:]
        avail_data_count = min(frame_count * CHANNELS * 2, len(data))
        return_data =  data[:avail_data_count]
        data = data[avail_data_count:]
        
        # Inflate end of the array with zeros, if there is not enough audio.
        return_data += bytes([0] * (frame_count * CHANNELS * 2 - avail_data_count))
        
        return (return_data, pyaudio.paContinue)
    except:
        print('Exception in pyaudio_callback...')


# open stream (3)
stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                output=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK_SIZE,
                stream_callback=pyaudio_callback)


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((HOST, int(PORT)))
#sock.listen(1)
#connection, client_address = sock.accept()
print('Socket bind succeed.')

try:
    while True:
        new_data = sock.recv(BROADCAST_SIZE)
        print(f"Incoming raw data : {type(new_data)}")

        rtp_packet = rtp.DecodeRTP(new_data)
        payload = rtp_packet['payload']
        ##break
        data += rtp_packet['payload']
        if len(data) >= BUFFER_SIZE and not is_receiving:
            is_receiving = True

            # start stream (4)
            stream.start_stream()
            print(f'Stream started, when {len(data)} bytes of data were received.\nThis causes {str(len(data) / RATE)} seconds of latency')
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\nClosing socket and stream...')
    sock.close()
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()
```

**pyrtp.py**

```
def GenerateRTP(packet_vars):

    #The first twelve octates are present in every RTP packet.
    #The first octet is the version number of the RTP packet.
    #The second octet is the padding bit.
    #The third octet is the extension bit.
    #The fourth octet is the CSRC count.
    #The fifth octet is the marker bit.
    #The sixth octet is the payload type.
    #The seventh to twelve octets are the sequence number.
    #The thirteen to eighteen octets are the timestamp.
    #The nineteen to twenty-four octets are the synchronization source (SSRC).
    #The remaining octets are the payload data.

    #Generate fist byte of the header a binary string:
    version = format(packet_vars['version'], 'b').zfill(2)
    padding = format(packet_vars['padding'], 'b')
    extension = format(packet_vars['extension'], 'b')
    csrc_count = format(packet_vars['csi_count'], 'b').zfill(4)
    
    byte1 = format(int((version + padding + extension + csrc_count), 2), 'x').zfill(2)


    #Generate second byte of the header as binary string:
    marker = format(packet_vars['marker'], 'b')
    payload_type = format(packet_vars['payload_type'], 'b').zfill(7)

    byte2 = format(int((marker + payload_type), 2), 'x').zfill(2)

    sequence_number = format(packet_vars['sequence_number'], 'x').zfill(4)
    timestamp = format(packet_vars['timestamp'], 'x').zfill(8)
    ssrc = format(packet_vars['ssrc'], 'x').zfill(8)

    payload = packet_vars['payload'].hex()

    packet = byte1 + byte2 + sequence_number + timestamp + ssrc + payload

    return packet.encode()


def DecodeRTP(packet_bytes):

    #return dict of variables from the packet
    packet_vars = {}

    byte1 = packet_bytes[0:2]
    byte1 = int(byte1, 16)
    byte1 = format(byte1, 'b').zfill(8)
    packet_vars['version'] = int(byte1[0:2],2)
    packet_vars['padding'] = int(byte1[2:3],2)
    packet_vars['extension'] = int(byte1[3:4])
    packet_vars['csi_count'] = int(byte1[4:8], 2)

    byte2 = packet_bytes[2:4]
    byte2 = int(byte2, 16)
    byte2 = format(byte2, 'b').zfill(8) 
    packet_vars['marker'] = int(byte2[0:1])
    packet_vars['payload_type'] = int(byte2[1:8], 2)


    packet_vars['sequence_number'] = int(packet_bytes[4:8], 16)
    packet_vars['timestamp'] = int(packet_bytes[8:16], 16)
    packet_vars['ssrc']  = int(packet_bytes[16:24], 16)


    payload = packet_bytes[24:]

    packet_vars['payload'] =  bytes.fromhex(payload.decode())
    #print(f"payload 4: {type(payload)} {payload}")

    return packet_vars
```